# Views, Pathauto, Views Arguments

Tags: drupal, view

I have been having extreme difficulty attempting to configure the following senario:

Each user on my site has a content profile aliased using path auto.  For example Jeff's profile is mysite.com/profile/jeff

I want to configure a views argument to output content created by this users so that when a user navigates to mysite.com/profile/jeff/term1 only content created by Jeff and taged with term1 is displayed.

Everything works fine while using views preview. The problem is that when I navigate to mysite.com/profile/jeff/term1 drupal takes me to mysite.com/jeffsprofile rather than the page view.

In views, the path is set to profile/% if i change it to say profiles/% - everything works fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is already using the path mysite.com/profile/jeff

try something different in your View, lige mysite.com/member/jeff

hope it helps

PR